# CodeSynthesis XSD xerces and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, xsd, visual-studio-2019, git-bash, xerces

I've downloaded a project

https://github.com/enoel14/sclparser

This is an XML parser, and I want to start it in visual studio 2019. But I can't figure it out how to build this libraries (on Windows) for using it with vs2019.
https://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/ tells that the last vs version that supported by .msi for windows is vs2013. So I've tried to follow this instructions:

https://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/extras/build-windows.xhtml

But when I'm trying to build xerces I get this:

[image]

Whats going on? Which file or directory it can't find?

Comment: You can try to run `make V=1` or maybe `make VERBOSE=1` to see the exact commands being executed by make. Most likely as a workaround you will need to reinstall mingw to the directory without spaces in path (not to "Program Files").

Comment: I downloaded the project you mentioned and tried to run it, but it didn't work. It shows 'cannot open source file "xercesc/sax/InputSource.hpp"'. I found that many header files are not in the folder, you should get these header files first.

Comment: This headers are in xercesc, I need to build it write way.. the error in gitbash is because ph.exe path is in Program Files (space in folder name). I reinstalled git at the higher level, but now I need to reinstall make..

Comment: Hi,has the original problem been solved?